# Ruby, each line in a file, match regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I do not understand why this code doesnt find the pattern in the string.
I open a file and read each line in the file and split it with "/t" and then I try to find a pattern. But it doesnot find it.
input file:

```
1553338_at/C1orf55  225142_at/JHDM1D    0.9075880395022964  
1553338_at/C1orf55  230778_at/---   0.9133682114964662
```

code:

```
input=File.open("/lalal/lalal.txt","r")

input.each{|line|

    keys=line.split("\t")
    puts(keys[1])

    a=/---/.match(keys[1])
    puts(a.class)    

}
```

output:

```
225142_at/JHDM1D
NilClass
230778_at/---
NilClass
```

I do not understand why it cannot find `"---"` in `230778_at/---` ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Works as expected for me with 2.0.0 on w7. What's your environment?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 1):

```
-
```

is a regexp reserved symbol. Use

```
\-
```

Even better, change your match line to

```
a = /\-{3}/.match(keys[1])
```

Comment: `-` is reserved only in character classes and only in some cases ! Like here `[0-9]` and the second one here `[0-9-]` doesn't have to be escaped. It has to be escaped here `[\0-\-]`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV ah, interesting.  I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: In case you're wondering what is `\0`: It means NUL or `0x0` in hex format, check out the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: lol forgot something crucial, you need to escape it if you used it as delimiter `-aaa\-aaa-`

Answer (score 0):

It does match (on Ruby 2.0.0).

```
/---/.match("230778_at/---")
# => #<MatchData "---">
```

Comment: It does not match if you do it like I do it with each line.